# Why is Number.prototype a Number

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

```
({}).toString.call(Number.prototype) === "[object Number]"
```

> The Number prototype object is itself a Number object (its [[Class]] is "Number") whose value is +0.

#### [15.7.4](http://es5.github.com/#x15.7.4)

Why would it be useful for `Number.prototype` to be a Number? (the same goes for every other built-in prototype which has the [[Class]] set to not Object)

I'm picking on `Number.prototype` specifically because I can imagine sensible legacy reasons for `Array.prototype` and `Date.prototype`.

Comment: +1 I always love the weird JavaScript questions.

Comment: We should have a `wtfjs` tag `:)`

Comment: should there be a particular reason?, I think this question is inappropriate... One could open a question for every unexpected behavior like `typeof null==="object"`, `NaN!==NaN` or any of [this list](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.equality). I don't think knowing why this happen will make any difference... It will be the same to think that the reason for all these is because "penguins can't fly", than knowing exactly why this happens. I will go for not constructive because it "solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" and dv because not usefull

Comment: Don't know for sure which is why this is a comment.  `Number.prototype` overrides the special `valueOf` method to produce a number, so the primitive form of `Number.prototype` is numeric.  Having `Number.prototype` behave like a primitive wrapper w.r.t. `valueOf` but have [[class]] `object` would be an oddity.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It'd be redundant with the "JavaScript" tag.

Comment: @ajax *I don't think knowing why this happen will make any difference... It will be the same to think that the reason for all these is because "penguins can't fly"* - Are you saying that you don't see the difference between knowing the true reason for something and making a reason up randomly?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I can see the difference, but I chose not to see it when it doesn't matter. If you put 2 js masters that know everything, and one chooses to think that the reason for everything unexpected is because "dogs can't talk", will it make any difference?, No, they will still need to make the same workarounds (even if the other guy studied in depth everything about the unexpected behavior)

Comment: @ajax333221 Well, that's your opinion. I don't agree. Knowledge is value. And more importantly, the desire to acquire knowledge is a virtue, no matter how insignificant that knowledge may seem. Also, knowing more about something, makes you understand the fundamentals of that thing better.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Well that's hilarious...

Comment: @MikeSamuel the distinction between "is Number.prototype an object that has function properties or is it an object which should behave sensibly wrt invocations of valueOf, etc" is a very good point. Make it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `Constructor.prototype` is an exemplar of the "type" defined by `Constructor`. Although things seem to get hairy for immutable primitives, and especially once you involve the boxing stuff, this exemplar concept still makes sense, with `0` being the "exemplar" of `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

> The Number prototype object is itself a Number object (its [[Class]] is "Number") whose value is +0

Why wouldn't `Number.prototype` be a Number object? Its `[[Prototype]]` is Object.prototype, so it still inherits from Object.

Comment: Because every other number satisfies either `typeof n === "number"` or `n instanceof Number`. It shouldn't be a number just like Function.prototype shouldn't be a function

Comment: But `typeof` doesn't simply echo the `[[Class]]` (e.g. `typeof Array == 'object'`), and `instanceof Number` would only be true if `Number.prototype[[Prototype]] == Number.prototype`. I think you can see the difficulty of that.

Comment: I meant every other number is either a numeric value or it's created through `new Number`. `Number.prototype` is just weird